# WPF Window Background ImageBrush not tiling

Tags: wpf, background, window

I have a window with a background image.  The image may change at runtime which really should not matter for this.

I want the image to be fixed to the top left (which it is) and not scale (which is also correct.  But I need the image to repeat (tile) when the window is made larger than the image.  I am doing ...

What am i missing?

TIA

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to set the [`TileMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.tilemode.aspx) property as well as the `Viewport` and `ViewportUnits`:

For example:

```
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="myImage.png"
        Viewport="0,0,300,300"
        ViewportUnits="Absolute"
        TileMode="Tile"
        Stretch="None"
        AlignmentX="Left"
        AlignmentY="Top"  />
</Window.Background>
```

Note: the second 2 segments of the `Viewport` attribute indicate the desired size of each repetition.  If you want to display the entire image, these should be the width and height of the image.

Example output:
[image: tiled magnifiers]

**Edit in response to comments**

If you don't know the size of the image to specify in the `Viewport` property, you can use a `Binding` with an `IValueConverter` to calculate it from the image.  I am convinced there must be a better way of doing this, but I haven't found one yet!

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Converter x:Key="Converter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Background>

    <ImageBrush ImageSource="myImage.png"
    ViewportUnits="Absolute"
    TileMode="Tile"
    Stretch="None"
    AlignmentX="Left"
    AlignmentY="Top" 
    Viewport="{Binding ImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"/>
</Window.Background>
```

Value converter:

```
public class Converter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var source = (ImageSource)value;
        return new Rect(0,0,source.Width, source.Height);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I am - <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush  Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top" ImageSource="/Panel;component/Images/woodpine.jpg" TileMode="Tile" />
    </Window.Background>        But it does not work

Comment: @Jeff - I hadn't seen this before, but you need to set the Viewport and ViewportUnits - I have updated the answer to reflect this

Comment: (+1) Better answer than mine, still using ImageBrush.

Comment: OK and thanks - this works as you describe but the image could change.  Is there a way that I can set the viewport setting to the actual size of the image?

Comment: You can only use either absolute viewport units (as above) or ones relative to the container (the `Window` in this case).  If you wanted your image to always take up, for example, 50% of the window size, you can remove the `Stretch="None"` and `ViewportUnits="Absolute"` attributes and change `Viewport` value to `0,0,0.5,0.5`.  I don't believe it is possible to make it relative to the size of the image itself

Comment: @Jeff, looking at the `TileBrush` code it turns out that `Viewport` is a dependency property, so you may be able to use a `Binding` to the same image source and an `IValueConverter` to get the desired viewport size

Comment: @Jeff - updated again with an example using an `IValueConverter`

Comment: What a fantastic response and answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't work. It is fine for 16x16 pixel images, but my 150x150 pixel image is scaled down to ~50% of its original size and thus 3/4 of the screen area are white.

Comment: @LonelyPixel it evidently does work - just not in your example.  If you ask another question with some more information and post the link here then I'll take a look

Comment: I found it out elsewhere. The PNG image must have 96dpi. That is an invisible metadata in the file. Some image editors seem to write a different value. You can remove the metadata with PNGOUT, then WPF does what it should. Seems WPF is the only software that cares about that data and produces all kinds of trouble because nobody else does.

Comment: Can anyone (@Jeff or other)  tell me that why it is not working if I try to use same code for grid or canvas background? I mean not using window background.

Comment: @ManishDubey is the grid or canvas stretching to fill it's container?

Comment: Sorry! I was wrong. It's working for canvas as well now.

Answer (score 8):

If you would like the entire solution in c#

```
ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"c:\your\image\source.gif"));
brush.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;
brush.ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;
brush.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, brush.ImageSource.Width, brush.ImageSource.Height);

MainWindow1.Background = brush;
```

Comment: I know this question is old. Just posting a possible back end solution.