# How can I tile an image inside of a canvas(or similar) in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am just making my first real steps into WPF. Every time I tried to make an attempt into it, I ended up getting a little frustrated due to the differences(between Winforms), and the fact that there isn't as much information out there on doing specific things.

I want am trying to figure out how I can take a 16x16 image and tile it inside of a canvas(or whatever the equivelant to a panel is in winforms) When I try to tile it by using the tile brush, although I can only get it to stretch the image to fit the canvas. I added the canvas to the top of my form to add kind of a header, now I want to add a background texture image to it. In winforms it was as easy as setting an image property to "tile" and another to "repeat" and it tiled the image nicely.

Can anyone help me out on doing this?

Comment: There are pretty good descriptions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097330/wpf-window-background-imagebrush-not-tiling) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742114(v=vs.110).aspx), can you be more specific about what you tried and what your problems are?

Comment: When you're getting "frustrated due to ... the fact that there isn't as much information out there", I'd strongly recommend to read a comprehensive book about WPF. There are plenty. My personal favorite is Adam Nathan's "WPF 4.5 Unleashed".

Comment: @Clemens I am going to buy that today, thanks for the suggestion. I appreciate it.

Comment: @nvoigt Thank you for the first link you showed me. It explained that the viewport and viewport units properties needed to be set.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim ib As New ImageBrush()
ib.ImageSource = New BitmapImage(New Uri("\images\sample.jpg", UriKind.Relative)) 
ib.TileMode = TileMode.Tile
mycan.Background = ib
```